# Displaying table containing dates and other records

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have this code which I need help with. The crux of the code is to print out all dates in a table and break after each week. The week starts from Monday. My sql code prints everything out but I'm not sure how to use loops to achieve the rest.

```
SELECT name, comment, hrs, CONVERT(varchar(20), timestamp, 120) AS timestamp, DATEADD(day, - DATEPART(weekday, timestamp), timestamp) AS Week_Start, 
           CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEPART(ww, DATEADD(dd, 0, timestamp))) AS WeekNo

FROM Tablename 

WHERE MONTH(timestamp) = '$month'

and YEAR(timestamp) = '$year'

order by wk
```

Let's say we have dates from 2001/01/01 to 2001/01/31

I want to get all days grouped by week for example if 2001/01/01 is Sunday i want groups like:

`Day  Date        Name      Hrs`

```
    Mon 2016-03-01  Username   8    
    Tue 2016-03-02  Username   8    
    Wed 2016-03-03  Username   9    
    Thu 2016-03-04  Username   10   
    Fri 2016-03-05  Username   10
    Sat 2016-03-06  -
    Sun 2016-03-07  Username   10
   ----------------------------------               
    Mon 2016-03-08  Username   8    
    Tue 2016-03-09  -
    Wed 2016-03-10  -   
    Thu 2016-03-11  -   
    Fri 2016-03-12  Username   10
    Sat 2016-03-13  -
    Sun 2016-03-15  Username   10
```

I'm using PHP/MS SQL 2008.

How do I break after each week?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want the dates from each row in their own column or do you want a string of dates in a single column?

Comment: Break on base of [weekday](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634550.aspx).

Comment: From the lack of information posted it is unclear what you are trying to do or how to help you write a query to do it. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @MikeDeluca, thanks for your reply. I want something like this:

`Day Date     Name   Hrs`
        
        `Mon 2016-03-01  Username   8` 
        `Tue 2016-03-02  Username   8` 
        `Wed 2016-03-03  Username   9` 
        `Thu 2016-03-04  Username   10 `
       ` Fri 2016-03-05  Username   10`
        `Sat 2016-03-06  -`
        `Sun 2016-03-07  Username   10`
       ----------------------------------

Comment: @SeanLange, I have editted my original question on how I want the display to be. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @syck, I keep getting the error message `WEEKDAY` isn't a built-in function.

Comment: @syck, I realised that function is for MS Excel and not MSSQL 2008

Comment: This is something you need do on the presentation layer (PHP in your case). Sql server has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It should be supported from SQL Server 2008r2 on. But Microsoft is not my world, anyways ^^. The first part of the date contains also the day of the week and may be of some help. But @Zohar is correct, this would be much easier to achieve in PHP.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Yes I agree it should be done on PHP side. That's is what I am asking for help on. The SQL side is ok. Achieving it in PHP is where I am stuck. I'm not a programming guru yet.lol...

Comment: @syck, I agree. PHP is what I require help in.

Comment: Have a look at the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class and its derivatives. It will give you the functionality you need. There are many examples in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL + T to change your query output to text.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT name, 
       comment, 
       hrs, 
       CONVERT(varchar(20), timestamp, 120) AS timestamp, 
       DATEADD(day, - DATEPART(weekday, timestamp), timestamp) AS Week_Start, 
       CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEPART(ww, DATEADD(dd, 0, timestamp))) AS WeekNo
INTO #TempTableName
FROM Tablename 
WHERE MONTH(timestamp) = '$month'
and YEAR(timestamp) = '$year'
order by wk

while ((select count(*) from #TempTableName) > 0)
begin
    select top 7 * from #TempTableName
    delete top (7) from #TempTableName
end
```

Comment: thanks. Your code works perfect The problem is that it only prints the 1st week data and stops. How do I get the rest?

Comment: It shouldn't be stopping.  If you have more than 7 records in #TempTableName, the while loop should keep going until all of the records have been printed.  How many records are in that table?

Comment: I have 27 records.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how there is an issue then.  If you have 27 records, delete 7, the loop should still go.  Are you sure you are deleting only 7?  Did you change anything in the code I posted?

Comment: No I didn't except for the TempTablename.

Comment: Sorry, without seeing your data I can't give any more suggestions.  Maybe if you make a sqlfiddle that would be more helpful so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Sure. I will make is an sqlfiddle. A moment.